# Como encontrar 2 ou mais palavras em um texto usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Olá, estou fazendo um campo de busca onde ele traz os dados de um XML.

Porém, ele só está trazendo se eu digitar o nome na ordem certa, por exemplo: no xml, o nome da pessoa é "Manoel da Silva", mas se eu escrevo só "Manoel Silva" no campo busca, ele não retorna os dados da pessoa... só retorna se eu colocar o "da" no meio do nome...

Pedaço do código:

```
$(xml).find('dado').each(function() {
            var doc      = $(this).find('doc').text(),
                razao    = $(this).find('razao').text(),
                fantasia = $(this).find('fantasia').text(),
                cidade   = $(this).find('cidade').text(),
                uf       = $(this).find('uf').text();

                //var regex = new RegExp(razao, "g");
                //var test = regex.test(nomeFiltro);
                //console.log(test);

            window.indexN = razao.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro);
```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: não vou dar a resposta, pois não tenho certeza de como fazer, mas acredito que você vá ter que usar algo como um like no query, segue a documentação http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode quebra o `nomedFiltro` em palavras fazendo um `.split(' ')`, então para cada uma destas palavras você cria um `RegExp` com o modificador `i` (case-insensitive) e verifica se o texto a ser testado passa em todas as validações.

```js
var registro = "Manoel da Silva";
var pesquisa = "mAnOeL SiLvA";

var match = pesquisa.split(" ").every(function (palavra) {
  var regex = new RegExp(palavra, "i");
  return regex.test(registro);
});

alert(match ? "Passou no Teste" : "Não Passou no Teste")
```

Comment: valeu!!! funcionou :D

Comment: +1 reposta certa e didatica

Comment: sabes me dizer por que retorna false se for assim:
var registro = "MAICON KNABACH FURTADO numerocpf";
var pesquisa = "Maicon Furtado";

??

numerocpf = meu cpf mesmo... botei isso pra nao expor meus dados heheh

Comment: você poderia atualizar a pergunta com este trecho de codico? se preferir você pode até mocar com informações falsas. é ruim de ver codigo num comentario.

Comment: Acho que o problema é no backend mesmo.. nem esquenta.. valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: A função every do array seria a mesma coisa de um foreach?

Comment: não, ao usar o `forEach`, você vai sempre percorrer todos os elementos além de poder modificar os mesmos, o every vai realizar uma verificação para cada elemento do array, por isto a função que ele recebe retorna um booleano, caso algum elemento não passe no teste (return false) ele não irá testar os proximos elementos e retornar falso, caso todos os elementos passem no teste ele retorna true.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia utilizar Expressões regulares, e alguma logica para gerar os curingas em sua consulta. Algo nessa ideia (acompanhe os comentários para entender a solução):

```js
function prepareQuery(query){
    return query
     // remover espaços do inicio e fim
        .trim()
     // troca todos os espaço pelo coringa /.+/
        .replace(/\s/, ".+");
}

function executeQuery(base, query){
    var regex = new RegExp(query, /*i para case-insensitive*/ "i");
    return regex.test(base);
}

// limpa body
document.body.innerHTML = "";
function print(value){
    // para imprimir do DOM
    var element = document.createElement("p");
    element.textContent = value;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function test(){
    var base = "Manoel da Silva";
    var tests = [
        "Manoel Silva",
        "Man Silva",
        "Manoel lva",
        "Manoel a",
        "M Silva",
        "Silva",
        "Manoel",
        "Man va",
        "M a",
        "M",
        "ManoelSilva",
        "Manlva",
        "Ma",
        "Pedro Silva",
    ];
    
    for(var itest in tests){
        var test = tests[itest];
        var query = prepareQuery(test);
        print(test + " : " + executeQuery(base, query));
    }
}
test();
```

```css
body { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/po0rg37z/)

Answer (score 1):

da p/ fazer assim também:

```
var string = "manoel da silva";
string.match(/manoel|silva/); // retorna manoel pois existe
string.match(/treco|silva/); // retorna silva pois existe
string.match(/treco|fuleco/); // retorna null pois não existe
```